# Filtering postal codes with Geocoder

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm attempting to extract the closer postal code to a certain latitude and longitude.
Reading here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#reverse-restricted

looks like it's possible to filter a certain type of results (including postal codes, if I'm not wrong).

My question is: is it possible to apply the same filter by using geocoding API?
Thanks in advance
Massi

Answer (score 1):

If you are reverse geocoding a latlng, you need no filters.

Just iterate over all results and pick the one with `"postal_code"` in its `results[i].types`

If you get no such result for a given latlng, it means there is no postal code that **contains** that latlng (as far as the Google Geocoding API can tell). The API won't return postal codes that are nearby, only those that contain the latlng.

Mind you, some buildings in Japan may be contained by many postal codes and the API won't return every single one of them. Example with 14:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D35.681185%252C139.763764

Comment: I just noticed your answer, sorry for the delay.

Eventually I opted for iterating just like you said and, in case a location didn't provide a postal code (e.g.: which one is the postal code for Ireland?) I returned the postal code of the town which was the closest to the returned LatLng.

This solution is risky, cause there may be no locations in that place, but I think it's good for most of Europe ;)

Thanks for the Japan reminder!